# Android WebView fails to load entire page because of missing favicon.ico

Tags: error-handling, android-webview, favicon

I've got a simple WebView that I use to load some URL.
The page starts loading (index.html, css files, etc - I can see it on my apache access log)
Then the android shows this error:

10-28 19:38:17.948 18990-18990/com. I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(376)] "error", source: http://**************** (376)

So I add an error handler in a WebViewClient as follows:

```
public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
    logger.e("Failed to open page: "
        + errorResponse.getReasonPhrase() + " "
        + request.getUrl().toString());
}
```

And I see this in logcat:

```
10-28 19:41:28.678 19506-19506/com.mycompany.myapp E/XXXX xxx.xxx.MyWebViewClient: Failed to open page: Not Found http://xxxxxx/favicon.ico
```

The same exact URL opens fine on desktop even if the icon is missing... Is there a way to get the WebView to ignore some of the errors?

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Your page should continue to load despite the error unless you are calling something from `onReceivedError`.

Is it possible that your apache logger is the issue?

Myself, I only present a connection dialog if it is for the main frame.

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest, WebResourceError webResourceError) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (webResourceRequest.isForMainFrame()) {                    
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, webResourceError.getDescription());
                displayConnectionErrorAlertDialog();
            }
        }
    }
```